# Circular dependency confusion

Tags: c++

I read Disch article here in c++ forum about headers
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

I have a code here that is somehow confusing

ResourceHolder.h

```
using namespace std;
template<typename Resource, typename Identifier>
class ResourceHolder{
public:
    void load(Identifier id, const std::string &filename);

    template<typename Parameter>
    void load(Identifier id, const std::string &filename, const Parameter &secondParam);

    Resource &get(Identifier id);
    const Resource &get(Identifier id) const;
private:
    void    insertResource(Identifier id, std::unique_ptr<Resource> resource);


private:
    std::map<Identifier, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> mResourceMap;

};
```

ResourceIdentifier.h

```
// Forward declaration of SFML classes
namespace sf
{
    class Texture;
}

namespace Textures
{
    enum  ID
    {
        Eagle,
        Raptor,
        Desert,
    };
}

// Forward declaration and a few type definitions
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
class ResourceHolder;

typedef ResourceHolder<sf::Texture, Textures::ID> TextureHolder;
```

Aircraft.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Entity.h"
#include "ResourceIdentifiers.h"

class Aircraft : public Entity
{
public:
    enum  Type{
        Eagle,
        Raptor
    };


    Aircraft(Type type, const TextureHolder& textures);

private:
    virtual void drawCurrent(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

private:
    Type mType;
    sf::Sprite mSprite;
};
```

I believe this is using the right way and the wrong way base on the article i read.

```
Aircraft.h
```

include

```
ResourceIdentifier.h
```

which contains a forward declaration of

```
ResourceHolder.h
```

Stated in the article that you need to use pointer to class or reference to class if you are going to forward declare.

In my code they use forward declaration but never use pointer to class. Its actually a template class

Thing is that when I got an error on my Aircraft.cpp about incompatible type

Aircraft.cpp

```
#include "Aircraft.h"

        #include "ResourceHolder.h" // --------- I got an error if this is not included.

    Textures::ID toTextureID(Aircraft::Type type){
        switch (type)
        {
        case Aircraft::Type::Eagle:
            return Textures::ID::Eagle;

        case Aircraft::Type::Raptor:
            return Textures::ID::Raptor;
        }

        return Textures::ID::Eagle;
    }



     void Aircraft::drawCurrent(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const{
         target.draw(mSprite, states);

     }

        Aircraft::Aircraft(Type type, const TextureHolder &textures) : mType(type), mSprite(textures.get(toTextureID(type))) //---------->  this is where i get an error if ResourceHolder.h is not included. Error: Incompatible type
        {
        }
```

The error:

```
Incompatible type.
```

But this is confusing. I included the
ResourceIdentifier.h
that has a class forward declaration of
ResourceHolder.h
, in my
Aircraft.h
.

Why do i get that error? Everything is linked together. ResourceHolder also has its own class declaration in diferent file which i did not included here. But every class has a declaration.

Also texture is a reference to the template class that is on `ResourceIdentifier.h`. Why do i have to declare the `ResourceHolder.h` again on Aircraft.cpp? Its already class fowarded on `ResourceIdentifier.h`. I didnt use any template class object. It is a reference.

Comment: TextureHolder is a ResourceHolder so you need ResourceHolder definition to use its functions.

Comment: @NeilKirk But its class forwarded on ResourceIdentifier. Im confuse.

Comment: ResourceIdentifier.h doesn't include the full definition of ResourceHolder. With a forward-declared class, you can only pass it by reference or pointer. You can't call any functions on it.

Comment: You didn't read the whole article. Scroll down to section 8 and all will be revealed.

Comment: @NeilKirk I see. So thats why I get an error when i call the get() without including the resourceHolder.

Comment: What I do is have two header files per class. MyClass-fwd.h which contains only forward declarations, and then the full MyClass.h. And only include the smallest one needed per file.

Comment: @AdrianMay Yes I read it. But still confusing because the code there doesnt include the template class tem but the a_fwd.h

Comment: You got to include the full definition somewhere, right? So if not there then where? It's already in the cpp rather than some header, so what more can you ask for?